# XML: how to align the items (Buttons of an HBox/Vbox) to the Right

Tags: javascript, xml, icons, sapui5, right-align

As the Title states.

My attempt:

```
<VBox>  
    <HBox alignItems="Right" id="Tabelle">
        <Button visible="true" enabled="true" icon="sap-icon://navigation-right-arrow" />
        <Button visible="true" enabled="true" icon="sap-icon://open-command-field" />
        <Button visible="true" enabled="true" icon="sap-icon://process" />
    </HBox>
</VBox>
```

Adding an `alignItems` -> to the Right so the Elements of `Hbox` will be put on the Right side of `VBox` but it seem not to work.

Why is not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HBox (and VBox) is basically a Flexbox, to put the content to the right use `justifyContent` not `alignContent` nor `alignItems`.

```
<HBox justifyContent="End" id="Tabelle">
    <Button visible="true" enabled="true" icon="sap-icon://navigation-right-arrow" />
    <Button visible="true" enabled="true" icon="sap-icon://open-command-field" />
    <Button visible="true" enabled="true" icon="sap-icon://process" />
</HBox>
```

[Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/aqsPnqltvkkN4k3e6QGK?p=preview)

Good reference for flexbox positioning: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Edit 1: Added Example
Edit 2: Grammar & Typos

Answer (score 4):

The best control I can suggest it `FlexBox`

```
<FlexBox
    alignItems="Center"
    justifyContent="End">
    <items>
        <Button enabled="true" icon="sap-icon://navigation-right-arrow" class="sapUiSmallMarginEnd"/>
        <Button enabled="true" icon="sap-icon://open-command-field" class="sapUiSmallMarginEnd"/>
        <Button enabled="true" icon="sap-icon://process" />
    </items>
</FlexBox>
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your contribution! I needed for it to be with HBox and with HBox justifyContent works

Answer (score 1):

Try with `alignContent` instead of `alignItems` OR combination of both. It seems that both have some impact.

You can check the [HBox API](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.HBox) documentation as well

Comment: Thank you for your contribution! for HBox justifyContent functioned better than alignContent